# How to build javaScript dictionary?

Tags: javascript

```js
var siteMap = {
  'CANADA': {
    'QUEBEC': {
      'MONTREAL': {}
    },
    'ONTARIO': {},
    'ALBERTA': {}
  },

  'USA': {
    'CALIFORNIA': {},
    'TEXAS': {},
    'FLORIDA': {}
  }
};
```

How do I make this javascript dictionary to convert to like this dynamically? I also don't know how deep the child goes. So, code should be handle any size.

```js
var convertedSiteMap = {
  'CANADA1': {
    ['CANADA', 'QUEBEC', 'MONTREAL']
  },
  'CANADA2': {
    ['CANADA', 'ONTARIO']
  },
  'CANADA3': {
    ['CANADA', 'ALBERTA']
  },
  'USA1': {
    ['USA', 'CALIFORNIA']
  },
  'USA2': {
    ['USA', 'TEXAS']
  },
  'USA3': {
    ['USA', 'FLORIDA']
  },
};
```

Comment: For starters, have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Have you done any work on this or are you asking others to write code for you without doing any work?

Comment: It's just an object, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired object structure in your question is not a valid javascript object, as you cannot put an array inside `{}` like this `'CANADA1': { ['CANADA', 'QUEBEC', 'MONTREAL'] }`.

If you want to set `CANADA1` like this `'CANADA1': ['CANADA', 'QUEBEC', 'MONTREAL']`, then you can use this function.

```
function convertSiteMap(siteMap) {
    var convertedSiteMap = {};
    var index = 1;
    for (var country in siteMap) {
       convertedSiteMap[country + index] = [country];
       for (var state in siteMap[country]) {
           var countryArr = convertedSiteMap[country + index];
           convertedSiteMap[country + index] = countryArr
               ? countryArr.concat([state]).concat(getProps(siteMap[country][state]))
               : [country].concat([state]).concat(getProps(siteMap[country][state]));
            index++;
       }
       index = 1;
    }
    return convertedSiteMap;
}

function getProps(obj) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var p in obj) {
        arr.push(p);
        arr = arr.concat(getProps(obj[p]));
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Use it like this

```
var convertedSiteMap = convertSiteMap(siteMap);
```

The outputted object will be like:

```
var convertedSiteMap = {
  'CANADA1': 
    ['CANADA', 'QUEBEC', 'MONTREAL']
  ,
  'CANADA2': 
    ['CANADA', 'ONTARIO']
  ,
  'CANADA3': 
    ['CANADA', 'ALBERTA']
  ,
  'USA1': 
    ['USA', 'CALIFORNIA']
   ,
  'USA2': 
    ['USA', 'TEXAS']
  ,
  'USA3': 
    ['USA', 'FLORIDA']
};
```

Note: you can nest objects as deep as you want.

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake on the the convertedSiteMap  notation. Thanks a lot it works great :)